# geoxml3 parseKMLString function not working?

Tags: kml, google-maps-api

I am unable to use Parser.parseKMLString(). 
Its giving me a error saying **Parser.parseKMLString() is not a function**. 
What i am trying to do is, read the KML file on the server and return the entire file as a json string which is then passed to the parseKMLString function.
But i am getting the above error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my mistake, it was just a typo. I was using parseKMLString, while the actual function is parseKmlString.